# Difference between regtest and testnet

Tags: testnet, regtest

I'm not sure what is the difference between regtest and testnet, they seem are different things but i cant find the different between them.

Does one have more stuff than others?

On the regtest, peer are seem to not being found.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Regtest is a network designed solely to be private and for testing only. You can create a private regtest network and do testing and experimentation with it. It is not a public network and has no peers for you to connect to.

Comment: So can i make another peer and connect directly to it?

Comment: Yes. You can use the `addnode` command and option to have nodes connect to each other. You can use the `-connect` startup option to make a node only connect to another node.

Comment: It keep showing connecting to peer or is that normal?
After i made a connection

Comment: Does it say that there is a connection?

Comment: yes, by the way, how do i add coin to it since i cant mine on it?

Comment: You can mine on it. Bitcoin Core has a built in miner specifically for regtest. Use the `generate` command.